# How to get the result of a loader if the screen was rotated during its job?

Tags: android, loader, screen-rotation

I heard loaders can help save the result of an asynchronous job during orientation changes. I have a fragment that executes a loader with some arguments. What should I do to reconnect to the loader? Important note: I don't want to restart the loader if its result was already processed by the LoaderCallbacks.onLoadFinished().
More detailed: I have a fragment with a text field. When the user inputs some text and presses Enter I should start search with a network request. I do it by starting a loader

```
 private void loadFirstPage() {
    LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
    data.currentPage = 1;

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(VacanciesAsyncLoader.ARG_SEARCH_TEXT, data.query);
    args.putInt(VacanciesAsyncLoader.ARG_ITEMS_PER_PAGE, Const.ITEM_PER_PAGE);
    args.putInt(VacanciesAsyncLoader.ARG_PAGE_NUMBER, data.currentPage);
    loaderManager.restartLoader(GET_VACANCIES_LOADER_ID, args, this);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // ...
    } else {
        data = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_DATA);
        restoreViewState(data);
        reconnectLoaderIfNeeded();
    }
}

private void reconnectLoaderIfNeeded() {
    EnumSet<State> loadingStates =
            EnumSet.of(State.REFRESHING, State.LOADING_FIRST_PAGE, State.LOADING_ADDITIONAL_PAGE);
    if (loadingStates.contains(data.state)) {
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(GET_VACANCIES_LOADER_ID, null, this);
    }
}
```

And I want to reconnect to it when the screen rotates. And if I processed its result, I don't want to trigger it again.

Comment: The loader reconnects automatically. You can call initLoader as many times as you want, but the loader won't reset. What do you want to update in the onloadFinished()?

Comment: @masp I'm afraid of that initLoader will restart the job even if it was completed and processed. For now, I've decided to save the state of whether I'm still loading something and if it is so, then I call initLoader without arguments. Seems to be working but I'm unsure if it is correct to start a loader with arguments and, after screen rotated, I call initLoader without passing arguments

Comment: Check this http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/08/implementing-loaders.html And it would be better if you could post some code because this doesnt sound like proper loaders functionality.

Comment: @masp I've updated the post. Actually I also use loaders on the same screen to load additional items and to refresh the items. For now, I keep state of loading and call initLoader() for appropriate loader and when loader completes I unset the loading state. It seems to work. However I'm not sure if it's a good practice to start a loader with some args and reconnect to it with passing null as args

Comment: I can't see all of your code so I don't know how it works, but restartLoader is different than initLoader.

Comment: @masp I've updated the post again adding more details. I need to call restartLoader because if the user inputs "help" and while data is being loaded he is able to input another word, let's say "kill", then I should stop searching "help" and start searching "kill"

Comment: I think @kcoppock 's answer is what you want.

Answer (score 4):

If this is just a one-off request, the typical pattern for this should be:

Initiate the request:

```
getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID, args, callbacks);
```

In `onCreate()`, check to see if the Loader is still running:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    // If it exists, init with null arguments (since they won't
    // be used) to reconnect the callbacks
    if (getLoaderManager().getLoader(LOADER_ID) != null) {
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, callbacks);
    }
}
```

In your `onLoadFinished()`, destroy the loader:

```
getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(LOADER_ID);
```

Assuming you've implemented your `Loader` properly, this should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you. This is a great pattern allowing not to store additional flags!

Answer (score 0):

You set this code in your Activity (for fragment).

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
...
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        >
```

Comment: not such a good practice to handle orientation changes this way.

Comment: I think it 's better for you to use "initLoader"

Answer (score 0):

This article helped me a lot in dealing with orientation changes regarding asynchronous tasks. It has to do with retaining Fragments:

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Hope this helps you as it did me

Comment: Yes, this is a cool thing. Sadly, I have to use loaders only, since I'm implementing a test task for a new job and the employer wants to see how I manage it